# A finite group of order $p^n$ cannot have a center of order $p^{n-1}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof, p-groups

I am aware that this is a relatively simple question if you use quotients, because $G/Z(G)$ has order $p$, and hence the quotient is cyclic, and therefore $G$ is abelian, so the center is the whole group, contradiction.

However, I am interested in a proof that does not use quotients, normality, Cauchy, Sylow, or similar tools. I came across one such proof, but I have a question about one particular detail. Here is the relevant part:

Suppose $|Z(G)| = p^{n-1}$. Then $G$ is not abelian. Take an element $x$ that is not in the center, and consider the elements $x, x^2, \ldots ,x^{p-1}$. The claim is now that none of these elements are in the center of $G$. For suppose one of these elements were in the center. Then $x^k \in Z(G)$ for some $k$ such that $2 \leq k \leq p - 1$. Now the center has order $p^{n-1}$, so $(x^k)^{p^{n-1}} = e$, and so $|x|$ divides $p^{n-1}k$ and $|x|$ divides $p^n$. **Therefore $k$ must be a power of $\mathbf{p}$.**

Why is the part in bold true? Why can't $k$ be any integer between $2$ and $p^{n-1}$?

PS: if you know of another proof that doesn't use any of the weapons mentioned above, please share.

Comment: By the way, I suspect that what it says is “Now the center has order $p^{n-1}$ so $(x^k)^{p^{n-1}}=e$...” (rather than $(x^k)^{p-1}$....)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @Junglemath may I ask why my answer was downvoted/not upvoted? My answer is correct and it was up before the other answers. I also spent a bit of time writing it out carefully too.

Comment: @Mike I don't know. I did not downvote your answer. But I also didn't upvote it because 1) you wrote much more than what was necessary to answer my very particular question, and 2) what you did write wasn't clear at all (to me, anyway). Contrast your answer with Arturo Magidin's. I hope you are not offended. Also, you cannot expect that every answer you provide will be accepted, just like no one else can reasonably expect this.

Comment: Thats fine @Junglemath

Comment: @Mike: It is generally fruitless to ask for reasons for downvotes; if the person giving the downvote does not comment at the time, you'll never find out. It can be anything from "I think this is wrong" to "I can't follow this" to "I disagree with some opinion or statement written in the answer."  My second-highest-voted answer is also the most heavily downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not well written; rather, $k$ cannot lie in the required range.

If $1\lt k\leq p-1$, then $\gcd(k,p)=1=\gcd(k,p^n)$, since $p$ is prime. Therefore there exist integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $1=\alpha k+\beta p^n$.

Now, 
$$x = x^1 = x^{\alpha k + \beta p^n} = (x^{\alpha k})(x^{\beta p^n}) = (x^k)^{\alpha}(x^{p^n})^{\beta} = (x^k)^{\alpha}e^{\beta} = (x^k)^{\alpha}\in Z(G),$$
since $x^k\in Z(G)$. But this contradicts the choice of $x$. Thus, none of $x$, $x^2,\ldots,x^{p-1}$ lie in $Z(G)$.

From this point, you can complete the proof by noting that $\langle Z(G),x\rangle$ contains at least all elements of the form $zx^i$ with $z\in Z(G)$ and $0\leq i\leq p-1$, and all are distinct (if $zx^i=wx^j$ with $j\geq i$, then $x^{j-i}=w^{-1}z\in Z(G)$, hence $j-i=0$, so $i=j$ and $z=w$). This gives you $|Z(G)|p = p^n$ elements. Thus, $\langle Z(G),x\rangle=G$, but then $G$ is abelian: any element in the generating set commutes with every element in the generating set.

---

**Added.** In comments I mention that one can show that the smallest value of $k$ such that $x^k$ lies in $Z(G)$ must be a power of $p$ (without using quotients, of course).

To expand: let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $x^k\in Z(G)$. We know that the order of $x$ is a power of $p$, say $p^t$. Let $\gcd(k,p^t)=p^s$. Note that of course $s\leq t$.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be integers such that $\alpha k + \beta p^t = p^s$. Then
$$x^{p^s} = x^{\alpha k + \beta p^t} = (x^k)^{\alpha}(x^{p^t})^{\beta} = (x^k)^{\alpha}\in Z(G),$$
thus, $x^{p^s}\in Z(G)$; as $p^s| k$ and $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $x^k\in Z(G)$, it follows that $p^s=k$, so the smallest $k\gt 0$ such that $x^k$ that lies in $Z(G)$ is a power of $p$, as claimed.

Comment: Two things: 1) should you have $1 < k \leq p-1$? 2) So is the author simply wrong about the bolded part in my question?

Comment: @Junglemath: Yes; I originally had $1\leq k$, and when I corrected I over-corrected. Yes, the assertion given by the author does not follow from what they have, though one can show in other ways that the least $k$ such that $x^k\in Z(G)$ must be a power of $p$; just not *that* way.

Comment: How, for example? Is it related to what the other answer outlines?

Comment: @Junglemath: For the reason I gave: if you take the least such $k$, and you write $k=ap^r$ with $\gcd(a,p)=1$, then you can use the gcd to show that in fact $x^{p^r}$ lies in $Z(G)$, and hence that $a=1$.

Comment: I understand how you showed that $x \in Z(G)$ in your answer, but there you did not claim anywhere that $k$ was the smallest value for which $x^k \in Z(G)$. Thus I don't see how the method used in your answer is the same as the one you just left in the comment.

Comment: @Junglemath: I don't think you really "grokked" what the argument was doing. I've added the proof of the assertion, and you can see that it is exactly the same argument as before.

Comment: What is $s$? I don't see where it was defined.

Comment: @Junglemath: I deleted some stuff that wasn't needed; it's given by the $\gcd$. Fixed.

Comment: @Junglemath: Basically, in **any** group, if $H$ is a subgroup, and both $x^r$ and $x^s$ lie in $H$, then $x^a\in H$ where $a=\gcd(r,s)$. In particular, the smallest $k$ such that $x^k\in H$ is always a divisor of the order of $x$.

Comment: I agree with the first sentence, but why does the second sentence follow?

Comment: @Junglemath: **It's the same argument!** Because $\gcd(k,|x|)$ will lie in $H$, and since $\gcd(k,|x|)\leq k$, it follows that $\gcd(k,|x|)=k$, so $k$ divides $|x|$.

Comment: (above should be "$x^{\gcd(k,|x|)}$ will lie in $H$"...)

Comment: I see now. Very good.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for the centralizer of an element $x \in G$ we have $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(x) \subseteq G$. Since in your case $|G:Z(G)|=p$, we conclude $Z(G)=C_G(x)$ or $C_G(x)=G$. In both cases it follows that $x \in Z(G)$. So $G \subseteq Z(G)$, and hence $G$ must be abelian.

Comment: The result in the OP follows from a different result that says that the center cannot have prime index in a finite group, which is essentially what you are saying. But I was mainly interested in the bolded part of my OP that was asserted by the author, but which turns out to be false, as pointed out by a couple of people here (as I suspected).

Comment: Ah OK, I concentrated on using elementary methods (as you pointed out, not using quotients, normality, Cauchy, Sylow, or similar tools).